# Python OOP programming issue when using MySQL connect

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, python-3.8

I am trying to write a backend that will be used for an IOS app. I know it will be technically the wrong way to do it but it wont be deployed.

My issues is i get the error

```
self.cursor(query)
TypeError: 'CMySQLCursor' object is not callable
```

This happens when i run the following from `main.py`

```
import database


db = database.database()

staff = db.getData("SELECT * FROM timesheets.staff")
```

Finally this is my `database.py` code

```
import mysql.connector

class database :
    conn = ""
    cursor = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='james',
                                       password='timeismoney',
                                       host='hallfamily.mycrestron.com',
                                       database='timesheets',
                                       port='6033')

        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        print("Done")

    def getData(self, query):

        #Checking if the user has applied a string
        if isinstance(query, str):
            self.cursor(query)
        else:
            return "You have provided a request that cant be processed"

        #Fetching all the results
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()

        #Returning back to the user
        return result

    def postData(self):
        print("Coming soon")


    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
self.cursor(query)
```

Try this:

```
self.cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: This has solved the issue. Many thanks. Is there any official documentation that i can use as i couldnt find the official docs.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-examples.html